# creating array with key value based on another array result in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this,

```
0:{tag_20: "2018051607234047", tag_12: "700", tag_20_credit_n: "529010804376-S"}
```

based on the above array I want to create new array like this

```
0:{code: "tag_20", property: "2018051607234047"} 1:{code: "tag_12", property: "700"} 2:{code: "tag_20_credit_n", property: "529010804376-S"}
```

I'm new this key value concept and **angularjs** so far I tried with this

```
var log = []; angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) { this.push('code: ' + key + ' property: ' + value); }, log);
```

but getting error.

Comment: That seems like a funky array, are you sure that is what it looks like? It seems more like an object.

Comment: What error are you getting? Help us help you.

Comment: the first one is what im getting as a response from server but i need to create a new one looks like the second one. means tag_20 become a value as well as ''2018051607234047'' become a value under key code and property respectively

Comment: this is what i get ["code: 0 property: [object Object]"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the array of objects and map the objects as new arrays with the wanted key value pairs.

```js
var array = [{ tag_20: "2018051607234047", tag_12: "700", tag_20_credit_n: "529010804376-S" }],
    result = array.map(o => Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([code, property]) => ({ code, property }))
    );

console.log(result);
```